# Copy value from one worksheet to multiple worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice

I just switched back to Microsoft Excel after years of using OpenOffice and I am struggling to do something that works in OpenOffice. I hope I'm not missing something obvious.

I have sheets for every month in a workbook. In January's sheet, I'll have a cell with a value. For example, A1 might contain a commission rate of 15%.  In OpenOffice, I could go to February's sheet, enter `=Jan!a1`, then could copy that, select all the remaining months' sheets, and paste. Each sheet would then reference the sheet immediately in front of it. March would reference February sheet `a1`, April would reference March `a1`, etc.
When I do the same in Excel, every sheet will reference January's sheet.  There are no absolute `$` in formulas.

What am I missing?

Comment: Care you provide specific formulas? Because I can certainly reference a sheet from one worksheet in another worksheet and make the cell reference absolute

Comment: Sheet names in formulas in Excel are not relative to the index position of the sheet they are copied from or to.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Excel; Look into using `ADDRESS()` to create a reference, which can be used with `INDIRECT()` to achieve the sheet-relative addressing you wish for.

Option 2: Revert to LibreOffice, which apparently does the same thing as OpenOffice.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel itself, you can't refer to other worksheets in a relative way. It is necessary to provide a name for the sheet.
However, you can use VBA and write a UDF function (it must be placed in the standard module) that allows you to create a relative reference to another worksheet. Listing of this code:

```
Function Ref(wks_ofs As Long, Optional adr As Variant)
   Application.Volatile
   If IsMissing(adr) Then
      adr = Application.ThisCell.Address
   ElseIf TypeName(adr) = "Range" Then
      adr = adr.Address
   ElseIf TypeName(adr) = "String" Then
      If Len(adr) = 0 Then _
         adr = Application.ThisCell.Address
   End If
   Dim id As Long
   id = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Index + wks_ofs
   If id < 1 Or id > Worksheets.Count Then
      Ref = CVErr(xlErrRef)
   Else
      Ref = Worksheets(id).Range(adr).Value
   End If
End Function
```

You call this e.g. `=Ref(-1)` or `=Ref(-1, A3)`

The first argument (Long) indicates an offset in sheet numbering (-1 means previous sheet, 0 current sheet, 1 next sheet). The second argument (reference or address text) specifies the address we want to refer to. This argument is optional, if omitted, the reference will be to the same address as the calling cell.